# External storage without supplementary power

Tags: usb, power-supply, hard-drive, storage

Is there an external storage without needing supplementary power? (i.e. a second power adapter)

EDIT: Would a very light-weight external USB SSD, such as [this Verbatim](http://www.verbatim.com/prod/usb-drives/professional-usb-drives/v3-max-usb-3.0-drives-sku-49808/), have a low enough consumption? (the manufacturer doesn't specify the consumption..)

Comment: Western digital sells a drive kit designed to work specifically with the Pi  http://wdlabs.wd.com/category/wd-pidrive/. I have seen plenty of other drive issues arise from power problems. This seems to be one of the few or only drives specifically designed for the Pi (without exteranal power) and hence having undergone extensive testing with the Pi.

Comment: @SteveRobillard : But why does it ship with a PS?

Comment: The base model does not and IIRC correctly (i think I saw it mentioned in the magpi) that it can run without external power. This may help https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/meet-314gb-pidrive/

Comment: I'm using a Western digital Elements drive on a Raspberry model B without problems. Other components in use are a monitor on the composite jack, active speakers on the audio jack and an Edimax Wifi-dongle on the second usb. I use a 1000mA power adapter for power supply. https://www.wdc.com/en-gb/products/portable-storage/wd-elements-portable.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of flash drives should not require additional power sources. This is a viable option should your storage needs not be too large.

Comment: please take a look on the product link in the edit of the question

Comment: That should be fine, but remember the Pi doesn't support USB3.0.

Answer (score 1):

There are no drives which can be guaranteed. Most modern portable USB drives (I use Seagate & Toshiba) can run without external power **PROVIDED** you have a quality power supply **AND** a good USB power cable.

Unfortunately these are rare; even "official" Pi power supplies do not meet the specs. See [Raspberry Pi Power Limitations](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/51615/raspberry-pi-power-limitations).

**If** you have a PSU/cable combination which is close to 5V (measured on pin 2,6 of the expansion header) it should be OK. Ideally the USB port should be loaded with a dummy load to draw ~600mA while testing.

Other options are SSD "drives" and USB Keys.

Comment: Could you please expand on SSD "drives"? Do you mean USB SSDs?

Comment: Would USB external SSDs use less current than USB external hard disks?

Comment: please take a look on the product link in the edit of the question